# SUM of Multiple COUNTs on Different Tables

Tags: mysql, join, count

This topic appears to be a popular one and definitely saturated in terms of the number of related posts, however, I've been working on this for 3 days and I cannot get this figured out.

I've been scouring this site and many others with potential solutions to this and some are executing, but I am not getting the expected results.

Here's what I'm trying to do...

1. SELECT and COUNT the number of reviews a user has submitted in the reviews table.
2. SELECT and COUNT the number of up-votes a user has in the reviewVotes table.
3. GROUP BY username (which is a key in both tables - usernames are unique, but exist in multiple rows).
4. Order the result set by the SUM of those COUNTs DESC. (This is something I keep trying, but can't get to even execute, so I am ordering by userReviewNum DESC right now.)
5. LIMIT the result set to the first 10.

The result set should give me the top 10 reviewers which is calculated by the number of reviews plus (+) the number of up-votes.

Here is my latest attempt which executes, but appears to be multiplying userReviewNum * reviewVotesNum and I need it to add them (but I have been extremely unsuccessful at any attempt to include the SUM command - so bad in fact that I am embarrassed to even show my attempts).

```
    SELECT
    reviews.username,
    count(reviews.username) userReviewNum,
    count(reviewVotes.username) reviewVotesNum
    FROM reviews 
    LEFT JOIN reviewVotes ON reviews.username = reviewVotes.username 
    GROUP by reviews.username
    ORDER BY userReviewNum DESC 
    LIMIT 0, 10
```

I've tried using a JOIN and a UNION and I can't seem to get either of them to work.

Any help anyone can provide is greatly appreciated!

**UPDATE:**

Here is the structure and some sample data.

Reviews Table (there are other fields, but these are the important ones):

**| username | comment | rating | productID |**

| foo | this is awesome! | 5 | xxxx |

| bar | i don't like this | 1 | xxxx |

| foo2 | it's ok | 3 | xxxx |

| foo | bleh - nasty | 1 | xxxx |

reviewVotes Table (again, more fields than this, but these are the important ones):

**| username | voterUsername | productID |**

| foo | foo2 | xxxx |

| foo2 | foo | xxxx | (the simple idea here is one user is up-voting another user's post)

So I need to count the number of reviews a user has in the Reviews table, then count the number of upvotes a user has in the reviewVotes table, and then order by the sum of those two numbers.

**Additional UPDATE:**
In the example above, here are the expected results:

**Username  |  # Reviews**

foo  |  2

bar  |  1

foo2  |  1

**Username  |  # Up-Votes**

foo  |  1

foo2  |  1

**Username  |  Total Sum**

foo  |  3

bar  |  1

foo2  |  2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try counting distinct reviews and votes like this:

```
SELECT
  reviews.username,
  COUNT(DISTINCT reviews.id) AS userReviewNum,
  COUNT(DICTINCT reviewVotes.id) AS reviewVotesNum,
  COUNT(DISTINCT reviews.id) + COUNT(DICTINCT reviewVotes.id) AS userRating
FROM 
  reviews 
  LEFT JOIN reviewVotes ON reviews.username = reviewVotes.username 
GROUP by reviews.username
ORDER BY userRating DESC 
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Thanks sashkello - I tried that earlier today, but that ends up giving me a funky result set that only includes one row from 10 users. Or at least the result set appears to do that.

Comment: @Rmilligan2372 If you run exactly the same thing as in your post? It should work unless your tables are not what I think they are - you can post some sample of your data and what you get from your query?

Comment: You bet - give me a few minutes and I'll add that.

Comment: This is closer - I had to remove the DISTINCT and it's SUM'ing the two correctly as userRating but the individual counts are still getting multiplied by each other somehow which results in userRating being incredibly larger than what it actually is.

Comment: @Rmilligan2372 DISTINCT is crucial here. What do you get if you use it?

Comment: I get something like this...

**Username | userReviewNum | reviewVotesNum | userRating**

foooo | 1 | 1 | 2

foobar | 1 | 1 | 2

baaaaar | 1 | 1 | 2

foobar | 1 | 1 | 2

They are all |1|1|2

Comment: Well, the formatting didn't work as I expected there, but each user that comes back in that query ends up having just 1 review, 1 up-vote, and then the sum is 2.

Comment: @Rmilligan2372 So, I suppose you don't have properly set up primary key `id` column? You definitely should do it, otherwise you'll be in a world of pain with this... It is still possible to count things, but it will be unnecessarily convoluted.

Comment: I have an index is set to the ID field

Comment: @Rmilligan2372 Try ID instead of id. I mean, I have no idea why my query wouldn't work here... unless there's something wrong with your index.

Comment: I think you're absolutely right here - I'm going to add a new unique auto-increment field to the reviews database and set it as the primary key and go off of that instead.  That will require additional time to change some code, so will hit it tomorrow, but I'm guessing your code is accurate.  Will verify and follow-up in the morning.

Comment: I couldn't let this go until morning, so I loaded everything up onto a test server and added a new unique ID key to the reviews table and it's working perfectly now.  Thank you!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT username, SUM(userReviewNum + reviewVotesNum) AS userRank
FROM (
    SELECT
    reviews.username,
    count(reviews.username) userReviewNum,
    count(reviewVotes.username) reviewVotesNum
    FROM reviews 
    LEFT JOIN reviewVotes ON reviews.username = reviewVotes.username 
    GROUP by reviews.username
    ORDER BY userReviewNum DESC 
    LIMIT 0, 10)
AS result_set
GROUP BY username
```

The group by there is, I think, required for the SUM to work.

Comment: Thanks SamA - the result set is kind of similar to what I was getting before only it's still coming back with incredibly high SUMs.  

User A should have 213 reviews with 149 up-votes for a total of 362, but what's coming back in the result set is 60,030.

Comment: Sounds like its adding everything in the SUM statement. Try changing the group by to group by all three fields.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT Res1.*, SUM(IF(reviewVotes.Username IS NULL,  0, 1))  AS UpVotes, 
userReviewNum + SUM(IF(reviewVotes.Username IS NULL,  0, 1)) AS TotalSum FROM (
SELECT username, Count(*) AS userReviewNum
FROM reviews
GROUP BY username) AS Res1
LEFT OUTER JOIN reviewVotes ON res1.username = reviewVotes.username 
GROUP BY Res1.username
ORDER BY TotalSum DESC
```

There result would be this:

> foo  2   1   3
>
> foo2  1  1   2
>
> bar 1   0    1